# recently i installed liferay in eclipse but i had faced unresolve error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, liferay-6

I installed liferay into eclipse and when I deploy project, it fires following error.

```
D:\liferay-plugind-sdk\build-common-plugin.xml:427: D:\bundles\tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib does not exist.
```

What could be the issue here and also provide solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check build.username.properties or build.properties file in plugin-sdk in which you provide server paths where plugins should be deployed.

In your case that path value is not pointing to correct server path and hence you are getting error message.

```
app.server.type=tomcat
app.server.dir=**THISWOULDBEPATHOFTOMCAT**
app.server.deploy.dir=${app.server.dir}\\webapps
app.server.lib.global.dir=${app.server.dir}\\lib\\ext
app.server.portal.dir=${app.server.dir}\\webapps\\ROOT
```

Provide app.server.dir property with actual tomcat path, then you will not get such error.